# VTK : How to set opacity to different object of a same actor

Tags: c++, vtk

I use VTK to display more than 10.000 lines on my window (do ask why ^^). But sometimes, I need to hide some segments. This is where the problem appears.

There are so many segments that I can only create 1 actor for all my objects. So, I can only set the opacity parameter for the actor.

I'm looking now to find a way to set opacity (or a kind of transparency) to my objects directly, without create again all my segment.

If anybody have solution ? (or tell me it's impossible ^^)
If needed, I can pick you of piece of code, but there is no tricky thing in my code.

Florian

PS (of course my english is bad, I'm french)

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a scalar point data to your polydata, where you set value to 1 if you want to see it, or 0 if you don't want to see it (remember to set the Modified() flag and to call the Update() method when you modify something). 
Then you have to create an opacityTransferFunction associated to that array like in this example:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/VolumeRendering/HAVSVolumeMapper

Comment: In fact, I associated a color vector to my segments. But only RGB for color. I solve my problem with RGBA, A for alpha canal. Alpha canal manage opacity from 0 (transparent) to 255 (fully displayed).